# Splitting and parsing xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am retrieving some data from an xml file and wish to split the result, parse it and then print it into an html element.

Here is an example of my xml file:

```
<Root>
   <Foo>
      <Bar>
         <BarType>Green</BarType>
         <Date>2020-09-03 23:40:55</Date>
      </Bar>
   </Foo>
</Root>
```

I would like to both split the string from Date and make it more human readable.

so instead of "2020-09-03 23:40:55" it would be "Sept 03, 2020 at 23:40"

Here is my function so far:

```js
function testFoo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/assets/TestFeed.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        // Alert if error in reading xml
        error: function (e) {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file");
            console.log("XML reading Failed: ", e);
        },
        // Runs if xml read succesully
        success: function (response) {
            
            $(response).find("Foo").each(function () {
                // Finds Date in specific xml node
                var fooDate = $(this).find('Bar:has(BarType:contains("Green")) Date').text();
                
                // Test for console to make sure it works
                console.log(fooDate);
                
                // add to the HTML 
                $("p").append('<span class="date-text">' + "Last Updated:  " + '</span>' + '<span class="date-first">' + fooDate + '</span>' + '<span class="date-time">' + "at " + fooDate + '</span>');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
var response = '<Root>\
        <Foo>\
        <Bar>\
        <BarType>Green</BarType>\
        <Date>2020-09-03 23:40:55</Date>\
</Bar>\
</Foo>\
</Root>';

$(response).find("Foo").each(function () {
    var fooDate = $(this).find('Bar:has(BarType:contains("Green")) Date').text();
    

    // format date.....
    fooDate = moment(fooDate).format('MMM DD, YYYY \\a\\t HH:mm');

    console.log(fooDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JimLegault  Remember to include the library momentjs....

Comment: Yup that did the trick. Thanks for introducing me to this very handy library.

Comment: Please be careful about just blindly throwing in libraries in your project. By default Moment is around 230kb.. that's really expensive when all you're doing is formatting a date. You could probably do the same thing in maybe 2-3 lines of code without it.

Comment: Ok,  add your answer and I will be pleased to upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in Date constructor:

```js
new Date("2020-09-03 23:40:55").toLocaleDateString("en");
// language can be each that browser supports
```

or

```js
new Date("2020-09-03 23:40:55").toLocaleString("en"); // whole
```

or

```js
new Date("2020-09-03 23:40:55").toLocaleTimeString("en"); // only time
```